# min width vs max width media queries CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I hope someone can help me with `media queries`?.

I have a series of `min width -max width` `media queries` .

However, if I remove the `max-width` syntax, the layout will break, but I can't figure out why this is happening.

If I remove the `max-width` syntax (including the `and`), the logic should be the same.. I'm saying, apply styles from `320px` up, then apply new styles from `480px` up

How can I convert this to just `min width`? (mobile first approach).

Am I missing something obvious?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
    #header h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    #nav ul li {
        margin: 0 .8em .6em 0;
        display: block;
    }

.......................more rules
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width : 800px) {
    #header h1 {
        font-size: 2.4em;
    }   
    #nav ul li {
        margin: 0 .8em .6em 0;
        display: inline-block;
....................................more rules
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _the layout breaks_?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set `max-width` if you are using **Mobile First Method**:

So, try something like this:

```css
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/ 
    }
```

In case you want to use the **Non-Mobile First Method** you don't need to set `min-width` and it looks like this:

```css
/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/     
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
      /*your CSS Rules*/ 
    }
```

Comment: Hi dippas,  Thanks for the reply. That's what I did , but removing the max-width causes the layout to break.. I tried media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {  and media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {